# Удаление из таблицы записей, которые не упоминаются в другой таблице.

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы.

```
id| name |  date
 1| item1|  2013-10-06 08:11:25
 2| item2|  2013-03-06 08:11:25
 3| item3|  2013-06-04 08:11:25
```

и

```
id|id_s | name |  date
 1| 2   | name1|  2013-03-06 08:11:25
 2| 1   | name2|  2013-10-06 08:11:25
 3| 2   | name2|  2013-01-02 08:11:25
```

Все это работает так:
Берется вторая таблица, LEFT JOIN'ом добавляется первая и что-то выводится.(id_s второй таблицы указывает на id первой)

Как удалить из ПЕРВОЙ таблицы те записи, на которые либо нет ссылок из второй, либо данные в полях date обеих таблиц содержат дату более чем месячной давности?

Т.е. в примере удалить из первой таблицы третью строку, потому что ссылкина нее нет во второй таблице, и вторую строку, потому что дата просрочена.

Comment: напишите запрос (select), выбирающий данные, которые вы собираетесь удалить. ...и змените выражение `select ... from` на `delete from`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удаление осиротевших записей

`DELETE FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT t2.id_s FROM table2 AS t2)`

PS. Никогда не используй такое удаление на реальных проектах

насколько мне известно, если использовать `LEFT JOIN` при удалении, то данные удалятся из обеих таблиц

выборка по временному интервалу

`SELECT FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
   AND t2.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: А почему нельзя такое использовать?

Comment: 1. Подобные запросы будут очень ресурсоемкими при работе с большими базами данных.
2. Это означает что база спроектирована плохо и надо запускать скрипт для очистки "осиротевших" записей с определенным временным интервалом.

Comment: Хм... А как тогда спроектировать базу хорошо?)  
В первой таблице хранятся события, а во второй даты когда эти события происходят. (ну, это если упрощенно). Если событие прошло, его же не мешает удалить?
Вообще, я собирался запускать удаление после добавления новой записи. Получится не так уж и часто, с другой стороны не успеет накопиться слишком много.

Comment: тогда так, при таком удалении осиротевших записей не будет
`DELETE FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
AND t2.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

> насколько мне известно, если использовать LEFT JOIN при удалении, то данные удалятся из обеих таблиц

можно по-отдельности удалять:

```
DELETE `t1` FROM `table1` `t1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` `t2`
WHERE ISNULL(`t2`.`id`)
    OR (
        `t1`.`date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        AND `t1`.`date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    );
```

Наши англоговорящие товарищи:

[ссылка1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192849)

[ссылка2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29204958)

[ссылка3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763245)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT t2.id_s FROM table2 AS t2)
```

Немного подправлю

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]